# Print text vector line by line in R

Tags: r, vector, printing, line

I accidentally got an object made by the function capture.output, which can be printed line by line, e.g.:

```
> print(xxx)
[1] "==============================================================================="
[2] "Initial design evaluation"                                                      
[3] ""                                                                               
[4] "Initial OFV = 28.9197"                                                          
[5] ""                                                                               
[6] "Initial design expected parameter "
```

However, when I tried to reproduce similar string vector, all the vector elements are printed on the same line. e.g.:

```
> a  <- c('a','b','c','d','e')
> print(a)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

I cannot find any difference between them:

```
> length(a)
[1] 5
> length(xxx)
[1] 5
> 
> class(xxx)
[1] "character"
> class(a)
[1] "character"
> 
> typeof(xxx)
[1] "character"
> typeof(a)
[1] "character"
```

I am wondering what causes the distinctive behaviors in print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a matter of the available horizontal space in the console. In my machine, at least, whenever two of the vector elements to be printed are wide enough that you would not be able to fit the two of them in one row, all the elements in the vector are printed one on each line. I believe that is what that first long string of equal signs does in your `xxx` vector. I could write the code I used to check this out, but it completely depends on the width of my console, so I don't think it would be useful to others.

Comment: You are right !!! once I remove the first long text string by print(xxx[-1]),  the output becomes normal.  This is an interesting trick if you want to print something line by line.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct so others can find it.

Comment: I did mark it. If with Rstudio, this should not be a rare issue.

Comment: Weird, it does not appear as marked to me. In any case, if what you want is to control how the output appears in the console, you can always use `cat`: `cat(xxx)` will print each element right next to each other, even if they're very wide. If you want to print `x` in different lines, you can do: `cat(paste(a, collapse='\n'))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that tries to mimic `print()` behavior:

```
print_oneperline <- function(x) 
  cat(sprintf(paste0('% ', floor(log10(length(x))) + 3,'s "%s"\n'), 
              paste0("[", seq_along(x), "]"), x), sep = "")
```

Here is how it works:

```
letters[1:5]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
print_oneperline(letters[1:5])
[1] "a"
[2] "b"
[3] "c"
[4] "d"
[5] "e"

xxx <- rep(c(
  "===============================================================================",
  "Initial design evaluation", "", "Initial OFV = 28.9197", 
  "Initial design expected parameter "), 3)
xxx    # regular print
 [1] "==============================================================================="
 [2] "Initial design evaluation"                                                      
 [3] ""                                                                               
 [4] "Initial OFV = 28.9197"                                                          
 [5] "Initial design expected parameter "                                             
 [6] "==============================================================================="
 [7] "Initial design evaluation"                                                      
 [8] ""                                                                               
 [9] "Initial OFV = 28.9197"                                                          
[10] "Initial design expected parameter "                                             
[11] "==============================================================================="
[12] "Initial design evaluation"                                                      
[13] ""                                                                               
[14] "Initial OFV = 28.9197"                                                          
[15] "Initial design expected parameter "                                             
> print_oneperline(xxx)
 [1] "==============================================================================="
 [2] "Initial design evaluation"
 [3] ""
 [4] "Initial OFV = 28.9197"
 [5] "Initial design expected parameter "
 [6] "==============================================================================="
 [7] "Initial design evaluation"
 [8] ""
 [9] "Initial OFV = 28.9197"
[10] "Initial design expected parameter "
[11] "==============================================================================="
[12] "Initial design evaluation"
[13] ""
[14] "Initial OFV = 28.9197"
[15] "Initial design expected parameter "
```

Additionally, you can play with your screen width as explained by the accepted answer:

```
options(width=10)
```